# Traceback when viewing @@personal-information page after following collective.userdata.examples Plone 4

Tags: plone

I have been following [collective.examples.userdata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata) in a Plone 4 site in an attempt to add more fields to the /@@personal-information page.

I am looking to add the following fields (all will be text string fields):

- Position
- Facebook
- Twitter
- LinkedIn

I have decided to just try and get the "Position" field working first and have successfully installed and activated my add-on without any trouble.

I do however get this traceback when I go to mysite.com/@@personal-preferences:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module zope.formlib.form, line 795, in __call__
Module five.formlib.formbase, line 50, in update
Module zope.formlib.form, line 758, in update
Module plone.fieldsets.form, line 30, in setUpWidgets
Module zope.formlib.form, line 383, in setUpEditWidgets
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <PloneSite at /peacehospice>, <InterfaceClass 
kcs.userdata.userdataschema.IEnhancedUserDataSchema>)
```

My add-on structure is as follows:

```
kcs.userdata
|
--kcs
  |
  --__init.py__
  --userdata
    |
    --adapter.py
    --configure.zcml
    --__init__.py
    --tests.py
    --userdataschema.py
    --profiles
      |
      --default
        |
        --componentregistry.xml
        --metadata_properties.xml
        --propertiestool.xml
```

The **kcs.userdata** folder is sitting in my src folder located inside of my instance folder.

I have plone.app.users included in my buildout under the `eggs` section

Below are the contents of my files:

**Location:** kcs.userdata/setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

version = '1.0'

setup(name='kcs.userdata',
  version=version,
  description="",
  long_description=open("README.txt").read() + "\n" +
                   open(os.path.join("docs", "HISTORY.txt")).read(),
  # Get more strings from
  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=list_classifiers
  classifiers=[
    "Framework :: Plone",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
  keywords='',
  author='',
  author_email='',
  url='http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/',
  license='GPL',
  packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup']),
  namespace_packages=['kcs'],
  include_package_data=True,
  zip_safe=False,
  install_requires=[
      'setuptools',
      'plone.app.users >= 1.0b7',
  ],
  entry_points="""
  # -*- Entry points: -*-

  [z3c.autoinclude.plugin]
  target = plone
  """,
  setup_requires=["PasteScript"],
  paster_plugins=["ZopeSkel"],
  )
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/adapter.py

```
from plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences import UserDataPanelAdapter

class EnhancedUserDataPanelAdapter(UserDataPanelAdapter):
  def get_position(self):
    return self.context.getProperty('position','')
  def set_position(self, value):
    return self.context.setMemberProperties({'position': value})
  position = property(get_position, set_position)
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/configure.zcml:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    i18n_domain="kcs.userdata">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
    name="default"
    title="KCS User Data"
    directory="profiles/default"
    description='Adds position field to user data'
    provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
    />

</configure>
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/**init**.py

```
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory("kcs.userdata")

def initialize(context):
    """Initializer called when used as a Zope 2 product."""
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/userdataschema.py

```
from zope.interface import Interface, implements
from zope import schema

from kcs.userdata import _
from plone.app.users.userdataschema import IUserDataSchemaProvider
from plone.app.users.userdataschema import IUserDataSchema

def validateAccept(value):
  if not value == True:
    return False
  return True

class UserDataSchemaProvider(object):
  implements(IUserDataSchemaProvider)

  def getSchema(self):
    return IEnhancedUserDataSchema

class IEnhancedUserDataSchema(IUserDataSchema):
  position = schema.TextLine(
    title=_(u'label_position', default=u'Position'),
    description=_(u'help_position', default=u"Fill in your position in the company"),
    required=False,
    )
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/profiles/default/componentregistry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<componentregistry>
  <utilities>
    <utility
      interface="plone.app.users.userdataschema.IUserDataSchemaProvider"
      factory="kcs.userdata.userdataschema.UserDataSchemaProvider"
    />
  </utilities>
</componentregistry>
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/profiles/default/metadata_properties.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_memberdata" meta_type="Plone Memberdata Tool">
  <property name="position" type="string"></property>
</object>
```

**Location:** kcs.userdata/kcs/userdata/profiles/default/propertiestool.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_properties" meta_type="Plone Properties Tool">
  <object name="site_properties" meta_type="Plone Property Sheet">
    <property name="user_registration_fields" type="lines">
      <element value="position" />
    </property>
  </object>
</object>
```

### TL;DR

Made a custom add-on using the [collective.examples.userdata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata) example, when trying to view mysite.com/@@personal-information I receive the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module zope.formlib.form, line 795, in __call__
Module five.formlib.formbase, line 50, in update
Module zope.formlib.form, line 758, in update
Module plone.fieldsets.form, line 30, in setUpWidgets
Module zope.formlib.form, line 383, in setUpEditWidgets
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <PloneSite at /peacehospice>, <InterfaceClass 
kcs.userdata.userdataschema.IEnhancedUserDataSchema>)
```

Can anyone lend any insight as to what it is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `overrides.zcml`, registering your adapter override:

```
<adapter
  provides=".userdataschema.IEnhancedUserDataSchema"
  for="Products.CMFCore.interfaces.ISiteRoot"
  factory=".adapter.EnhancedUserDataPanelAdapter"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also register a local+to-your-plonesite persistent utility like in [see link](https://github.com/LiberTIC/libertic.event/blob/master/src/libertic/event/profiles/default/componentregistry.xml)