# collective.data.examples custom field wont save data

Tags: plone

This is a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486251/traceback-when-viewing-personal-information-page-after-following-collective-us/16486461?noredirect=1#16486461).
I have used [collective.examples.userdata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata)
and successfully added a 'Position' text field to my User registration form. My problem is that when I go to my /@@personal-information page, fill in the field and hit 'Save', it just shows the field again and it is blank. I don't appear to be able to save any information to this field. I have tried running my instance in foreground mode but I can't see anything outputted to it when trying to save new information.

I don't know if this'll help but when I try to make use of the following TALES statement:

```
tal:define="membership context/portal_membership;
            info python:membership.getMemberInfo(user.getId());"
```

and then:

```
tal:replace="info/position"
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 334, in _exec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 431, in pt_render
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 620, in do_insertText_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /mysite/portal_skins/custom/home_page_view
   - Line 32, Column 11
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'info/position'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <PloneSite at /mysite>,
       'context': <ATDocument at /mysite/front-page>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7f1c681eeb30>,
       'here': <ATDocument at /mysite/front-page>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x9540260>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://dan-apache:8080/mysite/front-page/home_page_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <ZopePageTemplate at /mysite/home_page_view used for /mysite/front-page>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'dan'>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 77, in boboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 136, in traversePathElement
   - __traceback_info__: ({'language': '', 'description': '', 'username': 'dan', 'has_email': False, 'location': '', 'fullname': '', 'home_page': ''}, 'position')
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 50, in traverse
   - __traceback_info__: ({'language': '', 'description': '', 'username': 'dan', 'has_email': False, 'location': '', 'fullname': '', 'home_page': ''}, 'position', [])
LocationError: ({'language': '', 'description': '', 'username': 'dan', 'has_email': False, 'location': '', 'fullname': '', 'home_page': ''}, 'position')
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The traceback simply means there is no `position` key in the member info `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay FYI anyone else experiencing this, I went into the ZMI, went into portal_memberdata and then added some text to the Position field that had been created by my add-on.. Upon clicking save I could see the information in the /@@personal-information form, I am now able to update it on a per-user basis.